# Как добавить 3д модель на сайт

Tags: html, css, css-animation

У меня есть 3д модель,которую необходимо добавить на сайт.Модель называется ROLLS2.glb

Имеется вот такой макет : https://www.figma.com/file/96eZmcvKEtLoGTaqQ0EDCZ/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD?node-id=0%3A1

Всё сделано,кроме 3д модели,нужно её добавить на сайт.Тут есть необходимые файлы : https://disk.yandex.ru/d/KijAy8TRE1chLg

В папке img находится эта 3д модель под названием ROLLS2.glb

Comment: Вы работали с 3д?Мне нужно сделать так,чтобы сначала эта модель приближалась к нам,а потом её можно было чуть-чуть покрутить

Comment: Мне нужна помощь ваша при добавлении и анимации.Можете скачать этот зип архив,там всё есть,в папке img эта 3д модель,а потом скинуть мне его обратно?

Comment: Я вообще не разбираюсь в этом,и разбираться в этой нет времени,всё это нужно закончить сегодня или завтра.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Воспользуйтесь библиотекой Three.js или d3js. Не знаю какая из них поддерживает формат glb. Может обе, может и ни одна

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что библиотека three.js - может помочь.

В интернете полно гайдов. По сути, нужно подключить библиотеку, создать сцену, прописать путь до 3д модельки на каком-либо сервере и задать настройки поведению сцены.